# PHP Edit database entries not updating

Tags: php, mysql, sql, forms, mysqli

Making something so you can edit the database entries using a form but it's not updating, the first one with ID 0 doens't work at all but don't worry about that when you click edit, the main thing is that in the form instead of showing name,rank,text
it shows
text,name.rank
and it's also not updating when it press submit.

Here's a preview of what it looks like now: http://rumblegaming.co.uk/admin/records.php?id=1
Here is my code:

```
<?php
/*
Allows the user to both create new records and edit existing records
*/

// connect to the database
include("connect.php");

// creates the new/edit record form
// since this form is used multiple times in this file, I have made it a function that is easily reusable
function renderForm($name = '', $rank ='', $text ='', $error = '', $id = '')
{ ?>
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/strict.dtd">
<html>
<head>
<title>
<?php if ($id != '') { echo "Edit Record"; } else { echo "New Record"; } ?>
</title>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8"/>
</head>
<body>
<h1><?php if ($id != '') { echo "Edit Record"; } else { echo "New Record"; } ?></h1>
<?php if ($error != '') {
echo "<div style='padding:4px; border:1px solid red; color:red'>" . $error
. "</div>";
} ?>

<form action="" method="post">
<div>
<?php if ($id != '') { ?>
<input type="hidden" name="id" value="<?php echo $id; ?>" />
<p>ID: <?php echo $id; ?></p>
<?php } ?>

<strong>Name:</strong> <input type="text" name="name"
value="<?php echo $name; ?>"/><br/>
<strong>Rank:</strong> <input type="text" name="rank"
value="<?php echo $rank; ?>"/><br/>
<strong>Text:</strong> <input type="text" name="text"
value="<?php echo $text; ?>"/><br/>
<input type="submit" name="submit" value="Submit" />
</div>
</form>
</body>
</html>

<?php }



/*

EDIT RECORD

*/
// if the 'id' variable is set in the URL, we know that we need to edit a record
if (isset($_GET['id']))
{
// if the form's submit button is clicked, we need to process the form
if (isset($_POST['submit']))
{
// make sure the 'id' in the URL is valid
if (is_numeric($_POST['id']))
{
// get variables from the URL/form
$id = $_POST['id'];
$name = htmlentities($_POST['name'], ENT_QUOTES);
$rank = htmlentities($_POST['rank'], ENT_QUOTES);
$text = htmlentities($_POST['text'], ENT_QUOTES);

// check that firstname and lastname are both not empty
if ($name == '' || $rank == '')
{
// if they are empty, show an error message and display the form
$error = 'ERROR: Please fill in all required fields!';
renderForm($name, $rank, $text, $error, $id);
}
else
{
// if everything is fine, update the record in the database
if ($stmt = $mysqli->prepare("UPDATE Team SET name = ?, rank = ?, text = ? WHERE id=?"))
{
$stmt->bind_param("ssi", $id, $name, $rank, $text);
$stmt->execute();
$stmt->close();
}
// show an error message if the query has an error
else
{
echo "ERROR: could not prepare SQL statement.";
}

// redirect the user once the form is updated
header("Location: home");
}
}
// if the 'id' variable is not valid, show an error message
else
{
echo "Error!";
}
}
// if the form hasn't been submitted yet, get the info from the database and show the form
else
{
// make sure the 'id' value is valid
if (is_numeric($_GET['id']) && $_GET['id'] > 0)
{
// get 'id' from URL
$id = $_GET['id'];

// get the recod from the database
if($stmt = $mysqli->prepare("SELECT * FROM Team WHERE id=?"))
{
$stmt->bind_param("i", $id);
$stmt->execute();

$stmt->bind_result($id, $rank, $text, $name);
$stmt->fetch();

// show the form
renderForm($name, $rank, $text, NULL, $id);

$stmt->close();
}
// show an error if the query has an error
else
{
echo "Error: could not prepare SQL statement";
}
}
// if the 'id' value is not valid, redirect the user back to the view.php page
else
{
header("Location: home");
}
}
}



/*

NEW RECORD

*/
// if the 'id' variable is not set in the URL, we must be creating a new record
else
{
// if the form's submit button is clicked, we need to process the form
if (isset($_POST['submit']))
{
// get the form data
$firstname = htmlentities($_POST['firstname'], ENT_QUOTES);
$lastname = htmlentities($_POST['lastname'], ENT_QUOTES);

// check that firstname and lastname are both not empty
if ($firstname == '' || $lastname == '')
{
// if they are empty, show an error message and display the form
$error = 'ERROR: Please fill in all required fields!';
renderForm($firstname, $lastname, $error);
}
else
{
// insert the new record into the database
if ($stmt = $mysqli->prepare("INSERT players (firstname, lastname) VALUES (?, ?)"))
{
$stmt->bind_param("ss", $firstname, $lastname);
$stmt->execute();
$stmt->close();
}
// show an error if the query has an error
else
{
echo "ERROR: Could not prepare SQL statement.";
}

// redirec the user
header("Location: view.php");
}

}
// if the form hasn't been submitted yet, show the form
else
{
renderForm();
}
}

// close the mysqli connection
$mysqli->close();
?>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like mistake here:

```
if ($stmt = $mysqli->prepare("UPDATE Team SET name = ?, rank = ?, text = ? WHERE id=?"))
{
$stmt->bind_param("ssi", $id, $name, $rank, $text); // check data types here
```

If datatypes are like this:

```
$name = string
$rank = string
$text = string
$id = integer
```

Then it should be like:

```
if ($stmt = $mysqli->prepare("UPDATE Team SET name = ?, rank = ?, text = ? WHERE id=?"))
{
$stmt->bind_param("sssi", $name, $rank, $text, $id);
```

Comment: Thanks, this fixed it but they're still not showing in the correct order.

Comment: any clue why they're not showing in the correct order?